# Combine multiple Uint8List.view

Tags: dart, memory

Assume I want to concatenate N Uint8Lists into a single one.
The naive approach is to simple copy all elements into a new list. However, that seems rather memory in efficient. Instead, I want to create a single Uint8List "view" which simply indexes into the appropriate underlying list instead of copying all its content.
In C++ I'd usually just overwrite operator[] but I am not quite certain how to do this with Uint8Lists in Dart.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can make a `View` class that overrides `operator[]`.  In Dart, you could do the same thing:

```dart
class View<T> {
  View(this._lists);

  List<List<T>> _lists;

  T operator [](int index) {
    for (var list in _lists) {
      if (index < list.length) {
        return list[index];
      }
      index -= list.length;
    }
    throw RangeError('...');
  }
}
```

You could stop there, but doing just that usually wouldn't be enough in either language.  In C++, you'd also want to provide `begin()` and `end()` methods for [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to work.  Similarly, in Dart, you'd want to provide the [`Iterable` interface](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) so that [`for`-`in`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops) would work.

Luckily [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) (note that this is separate from `dart:collection`) provides a [`CombinedListView`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/CombinedListView-class.html) class that does that work for you.  For example:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var list1 = Uint8List.fromList([1, 2, 3]);
  var list2 = Uint8List.fromList([4, 5, 6]);
  var list3 = Uint8List.fromList([7, 8, 9]);
  var view = CombinedListView<int>([list1, list2, list3]);

  for (var i in view) {
    print(i);
  }
}
```